# Why serial code is faster than concurrent.futures in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am using the following code to process some pictures for my ML project and I would like to parallelize it.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import concurrent.futures

def track_ids(seq):
    '''The func is so big I can not put it here'''
    ood = {}
    for i in seq:
        # I load around 500 images and process them
        ood[i] = some Value
    return ood

seqs = []
for seq in range(1, 10):# len(seqs)+1):
    seq = txt+str(seq)
    seqs.append(seq)
    # serial call of the function
    track_ids(seq)

#parallel call of the function
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=mp.cpu_count()) as ex:
    ood_id = ex.map(track_ids, seqs)
```

if I run the code serially it takes `3.0` minutes but for parallel with concurrent, it takes `3.5` minutes.
can someone please explain why is that? and present a way to solve the problem.

btw, I have 12 cores.
Thanks

Comment: hard to say... nothing is obviously wrong with the structure of the code. Any time the words "speed" come out of your mouth, you should be profiling. Admittedly profiling multiprocessing code is more difficult than single process, but there are plenty of tools out there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brief example of how one might go about profiling multiprocessing code vs serial execution:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from cProfile import Profile
from pstats import Stats
import concurrent.futures

def track_ids(seq):
    '''The func is so big I can not put it here'''
    ood = {}
    for i in seq:
        # I load around 500 images and process them
        ood[i] = some Value
    return ood

def profile_seq():
    p = Profile() #one and only profiler instance
    p.enable()
    seqs = []
    for seq in range(1, 10):# len(seqs)+1):
        seq = txt+str(seq)
        seqs.append(seq)
        # serial call of the function
        track_ids(seq)
    p.disable()
    return Stats(p), seqs


def track_ids_pr(seq):
    p = Profile() #profile the child tasks
    p.enable()
    
    retval = track_ids(seq)
    
    p.disable()
    return (Stats(p, stream="dummy"), retval)
    
def profile_parallel():
    p = Profile() #profile stuff in the main process
    p.enable()
    
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=mp.cpu_count()) as ex:
        retvals = ex.map(track_ids_pr, seqs)
        
    p.disable()
    s = Stats(p)
    
    out = []
    for ret in retvals:
        s.add(ret[0])
        out.append(ret[1])
        
    return s, out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stat, retval = profile_parallel()
    stat.print_stats()
```

---

**EDIT:** Unfortunately I found out that `pstat.Stats` objects cannot be used normally with `multiprocessing.Queue` because it is not pickleable (which is needed for the operation of `concurrent.futures`). Evidently it normally will store a reference to a file for the purpose of writing statistics to that file, and if none is given, it will by default grab a reference to `sys.stdout`. We don't actually need that reference however until we actually want to print out the statistics, so we can just give it a temporary value to prevent the pickle error, and then restore an appropriate value later. The following example should be copy-paste-able and run just fine rather than the pseudocode-ish example above.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from cProfile import Profile
from pstats import Stats
import sys

def isprime(x):
    for d in range(2, int(x**.5)):
        if x % d == 0:
            return False
    return True

def foo(retq):
    p = Profile()
    p.enable()
    
    primes = []
    max_n = 2**20
    for n in range(3, max_n):
        if isprime(n):
            primes.append(n)
        
    p.disable()
    retq.put(Stats(p, stream="dummy")) #Dirty hack: set `stream` to something picklable then override later

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    
    p1 = Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    
    p2 = Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p2.start()
    
    s1 = q.get()
    s1.stream = sys.stdout #restore original file
    s2 = q.get()
  # s2.stream #if we are just adding this `Stats` object to another the `stream` just gets thrown away anyway.
    
    s1.add(s2) #add up the stats from both child processes.
    s1.print_stats() #s1.stream gets used here, but not before. If you provide a file to write to instead of sys.stdout, it will write to that file)
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: The goal of profiling would be to hopefully identify where the bottleneck is in your code. To me it's likely you may have already been maxing out for example the hard drive where all the images are stored, in which case you are just adding overhead in an already constrained system. Profiling will help you find out for sure however where the holdup is

Comment: I get the following error while profiling, which comes from the `for ret in retvals: etc.`
`concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

Comment: @Dariyoush My bad for not testing.. Unfortunately `pstat.Stats` is not normally picklable which is needed for sending results back from a child process. The typical solution (as far as I can understand from the profiling documentation) would be to write the stats to file from the child process, then re-open those files to load them into the main process... alternatively, we can just give the `Stats` constructor a fake file stream which is picklable because it doesn't really need it anyway.